# Confusing operators in algebra for newbies

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, cryptography

I am reading an article about group signatures - a concept in application cryptography.
There are 3 operators I'm not very clear on what they mean. Please explain to me or where can I search?

[image]

I'm reading the article [*A Practical and Provably Secure Coalition-Resistant Group Signature Scheme*](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Egts/paps/acjt00.pdf) by Giuseppe Ateniese, Jan Camenisch.. My question is related to the Setup protocol section 4.1 'The Group Signature Scheme'. Thank you for your help

Comment: Your question would be much improved if you added information about the article you're reading.

Comment: I'm reading the article 'A Practical and Provably Secure Coalition-Resistant Group Signature Scheme' by Giuseppe Ateniese, Jan Camenisch..
My question is related to the Setup protocol section 4.1 'The Group Signature Scheme'.  Thank you for your help

Comment: That goes in your question via an [edit] - important clarifications should be added to your question, as information in the comments is easier to miss.

Comment: 2) $\operatorname{QR}(n)$ is the set of quadratic residues mod $n$; this is discussed on p. 5 after Assumption 2. 3) $\mathbb{Z}_{n}^{*}$ is the group of units mod $n$.

Comment: 1st is [another notation to assign a random element](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/62674/18298)